# Laravel SUM One To Many (Inverse) / Belongs To Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have `stuffs` table where will be saved only stuff title.

Stuffs table:

```
id
title
```

Also I've `user_stuffs` table where each user has `n` stuff volume.

User stuffs table:

```
id
stuff_id
user_id
volume
```

How I can `SUM` each stuffs volumes and get like this result:

```
{
  "title": "Stuff Title",
  "total": 7634
}
```

I tried using only sql exec like this query but how I can do it correctly in Laravel?

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 
    stuffs.id, 
    stuffs.title, 
    SUM(user_stuffs.volume) AS total 
FROM `user_stuffs`
INNER JOIN stuffs ON user_stuffs.stuff_id = stuffs.id
GROUP BY user_stuffs.stuff_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DB::table('user_stuffs')
    ->Join('stuffs','stuffs.id','=','user_stuffs.stuff_id')
    ->select('stuffs.id','stuffs.title',DB::raw('SUM(user_stuffs.volume) AS total'))
    ->groupBy('user_stuffs.stuff_id','stuffs.id', 
    'stuffs.title')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Error `Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'database.stuffs.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `stuffs`.`id`, `stuffs`.`title`, SUM(user_stuffs.volume) AS total from `user_stuffs` inner join `stuffs` on `stuffs`.`id` = `user_stuffs`.`stuff_id` group by `user_stuffs`.`stuff_id`)'`

Comment: I have updated the answer give it a try and let me know